# Converting Serialized Java Classes Between XML and Binary

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization

I am using Java native serialization along with a dynamic proxy to save the parameters and returns of a series of method calls to a file.

I would like to convert the binary file that is generated to and from XML.

Is this something that I will need to reinvent, or are there already tools out there that can do this?

Comment: Any particular XML format? Base64 encode and wrap? The binary Java serialisation format is unparsable without the Java classes.

Comment: Thats a good point. I will have the java classes available. The XML format needs to be human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castor or XStream are two solid choices. XStream has the benefit of drop dead simple usage

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).